# Trouble with nested and infinite loops

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble looping through cells in a column. When using the commented out If statement instead of the 'Exit Do' below it I start and infinite loop. For some reason my code isn't moving down through the cells even with 'cell.Offset().Select'. When running the code it just returns the first box instead of checking each box until it gets to an empty box and leaving the 'Do loop' to start up the 'for loop' again.

```
'Macro is designed to Fill in blank spaces in column "F" depending on Passed, Non-Executed, or Failed Steps.
'Should fill in "F" if there exists an "F" in the filled in steps under it.
'Fills in "NE" if there is one present and no "F" present
'Fills in "P" if all else fails
Sub AutoFill()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
'Setting Variables, cell is used as current cell and rng is used as complete column of cells to check

Dim pf As String
'Variable that is assigned the cell values to check

'Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)
Set rng = Range("F36:F66")
'Range setters, top one is input by the user once ran. It is input like follows '$Column$RowStart:$Column$RowEnd

For Each cell In rng
'Loops through set range and check each cell for the following

    If IsEmpty(cell) = True And IsEmpty(Range("B" & cell.Row)) = True Then
    'Checks if cell is empty and if the cell in the same row and column "B"

        If IsEmpty(cell.Offset(1, 0)) = False Then
        'Checks if cell under 'current cell' is empty

            Dim TrackedCell As Range
            Set TrackedCell = cell
            'Creates variable that marks 'current empty cell'

            pf = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value
            'Assigns cell values of the cell under current cell to variable

            cell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            'Moves down 1 cell


            'MsgBox "The value is" & TrackedCell.Value


            Do
            'Creates loop


            'MsgBox "Loop starts"



                If IsEmpty(TrackedCell) = True And pf = "F" Or (TrackedCell.Value = "P" And pf = "F") Or (TrackedCell.Value = "NE" And pf = "F") Then
                'Checks if 'current empty cell' is still empty and if current cell value equals "F"
                    TrackedCell.Value = "F"
                    TrackedCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                    'Sets 'current empty cell' to "F" and highlights cell
                    'MsgBox "If works"




                ElseIf (IsEmpty(TrackedCell) = True And pf = "NE") Or (TrackedCell.Value = "P" And pf = "NE") Then
                'Checks if 'current empty cell' is still empty and if current cell value equals "NE"
                    TrackedCell.Value = "NE"
                    TrackedCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                    'Sets 'current empty cell' to "NE" and highlights cell




                ElseIf IsEmpty(TrackedCell) = True And pf = "P" Then
                'Checks if 'current empty cell' is still empty and if current cell value equals "P"
                    TrackedCell.Value = "P"
                    TrackedCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                    'Sets 'current empty cell' to "P" and highlights cell
                    'Exit Do
                    'exits loop
                End If

                'MsgBox "What now"

                pf = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value
                cell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                'Moves down 1 cell

                'MsgBox "Should have moved down a cell"
                'If IsEmpty(pf) = True Then
                    'MsgBox "Exit If Used"
                    'Exit Do
                'End If
                'exits loop
                Exit Do
                'MsgBox "Not Exit If"
            Loop Until IsEmpty(pf) = True
            'Loops through range checking and moving down cells until the next empty cell is found


        End If
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

The MsgBoxes were for me to check where there were issues in the program while running.

To explain further. I'm trying to fill in an empty cell in a column full of "F"'s, "P"'s, and "NE"'s. The idea is if an "F" is present between this empty cell in the column and the next empty cell in the same column than the top empty cell should have an "F" put in it. The same idea goes for "NE", but "F" would over power "NE". If there exists neither of those in the full cells under the empty cell a "P" is put it. Basically tests were done and were grouped in categories. If one test failed or was not executed in the category the whole thing is labeled its respective label.

In the sheet below I have an example of how it would look. I'm trying to make the macro autofill the sub or super test's empty box depending on the Procedures under it.

[Excel test sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpnvH.png)

Comment: See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: While `while` loops have their use... i just prefer set limits with a `for x = 1 to 100` kind of logic. That way, you wont run in an infinite loop ever.

Comment: Note: the loop `For each cell in rng` only preceeds to the next cell after it hits the `Next cell` code line. The cell used for the `Do`-loop isn't changing inside the `Do`-loop; it's changing after exiting the Do-loop, and before starting that section of code all over again.